# Confusion in DS160 address and passport address

Tags: passports, paperwork, international-travel, us-visa-waiver-program, f1-visas

I am from India. I will be applying for F1 Visa. While filling the DS160 form I got confused about what to fill in my home address and mailing address. My present address on my passport is of the college. Now my degree is completed and I am residing now at my permanent address(home). I am confused - what should I fill in the mailing address, should the mailing address of DS160 be the same as the present address of the passport or it has to be of my home as I am currently residing there?

Answer (score 2):

You should fill out your current address, not the one on the passport.

You do no longer live on the college address and will not (or not easily) receive mail via that address.

If you have a space to put an explanation you can mention you moved from the address in the passport. But if there is no such space, just ignore the address in the passport.